# Pandas groupby propagates strange typecasting behavior

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am a longtime R user trying to make the shift to Python... It's gone well until I encountered some strange automatic typecasting by Pandas when I perform a `groupby` function on my frame. I have a Pandas dataframe, `df`, resembling the following:

```
    id      date        numresp
0   1943    2002-11-08  1
1   1943    2002-11-08  1
2   1943    2003-02-17  1
3   1943    2003-02-17  1
4   1943    2003-02-17  1
```

My objective is, for every unique `id`, I would like to know the `min` and `max` dates so that I could calculate the time delta in days. I am currently using `pandas.groupby` to calculate the arrays of max and min dates:

```
max_dates = df.groupby('id').date.max().values
min_dates = df.groupby('id').date.min().values
```

Here is the head of `max_dates`:

```
(array(['2009-08-19T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
        '2010-11-11T18:00:00.000000000-0600',
        '2009-03-22T19:00:00.000000000-0500', ...,
        '2010-06-09T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
        '2014-04-30T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
        '2009-01-05T18:00:00.000000000-0600'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

and here is the head of `min_dates`:

```
array([  9.72604800e+17,   8.88883200e+17,   9.71395200e+17, ...,
         8.47065600e+17,   9.40809600e+17,   9.56016000e+17]))
```

The results are quite puzzling... the `max_dates` array is comprised of `numpy.datetime64` types, but the `min_dates` array is made up of `numpy.float64` types:

```
>>> type(max_dates[0]), type(min_dates[0])
(numpy.datetime64, numpy.float64)
```

I *know* that the `date` column is a `datetime64` type:

```
>>>df.dtypes
id                 object
date       datetime64[ns]
numresp             int64
dtype: object
```

and yet the `groupby` function is still propagating this bizarre type casting, but only for the `min_dates` array... I am able to perform the subtraction I was hoping for, but I'd still like to know why Pandas (or Numpy?) is causing one of my arrays to be cast to float64 from datetime?

### Edit:

- My pandas version: 0.16.2
- My numpy version: 1.9.2

Comment: Upgrade your pandas, this doesn't seem to be an issue on 0.17?

Comment: @AndyHayden, is this a known issue in 0.16.x?  Unfortunately, I'm running it on a server where I don't have permissions to upgrade it... if it's a known issue, I can likely make the business case, but if not I'd like to get to the root of the behavior..

Comment: Could you show how to create some example data that reproduces the weird casting behaviour?